# SalesforceDX - standard object, custom fields are not being deployed

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, cli

I currently testing the possibilites of SalesforceDX and found couple of issues with deploying packages from Prod to Scratch orgs. Does anyone have experienced issues with deploying custom fields of standard objects? [image]

I have retrieved the package from Prod,  unpacked it, converted and pushed to my Scratch org but this one class along with required fields on Contact can't be pushed. Can anyone encounter similar problems with DX?

EDIT:

When I put the class which uses it to foceignore it doesn't throw any errors, fields are simply not deployed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>BumpRequests</fullName>
    <types>
        <members>BUMP_ErrorMailer</members>
        <members>BUMP_SheetsReaderBumpRequest</members>
        <members>CareerPathTriggerHandler</members>
        <members>DatesOverlap</members>
        <members>GoogleDocCallout</members>
        <members>GoogleParser</members>
        <members>Mailer</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>CareerPathTrigger</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Career_path__c.Active__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Applies_from__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Assigned_office__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Bump_amount__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Contact__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Current_position__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Current_rate__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Current_salary__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Employment_type__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.External_Id__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Leaders_allowance__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Netguru_Role__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.New_Position__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.New_leader__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.New_office__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Reports_to__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Requested_date__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Role_End_Date__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Role_Start_Date__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Salary__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Status__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Team_Leader_Netguru__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Team_s_name__c</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Values_copied__c</members>
        <members>Contact.Assigned_Office__c</members>
        <members>Contact.Employment_type__c</members>
        <members>Contact.Initial_salary__c</members>
        <members>Contact.Netguru_Offboarding_Date__c</members>
        <members>Contact.Role__c</members>
        <members>Contact.Team_Leader__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Career_path__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Netguru_Roles</members>
        <members>Offices</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Career_path__c-Employment history Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Career_path__c.All</members>
        <members>Career_path__c.Career_paths_HRBP_Home</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: `.forceignore` instructs Salesforce DX to ignore metadata, so that is not going to be what you want. Could you edit your question to show how you are performing the deployment, and include your `package.xml`?

Comment: added package.xml to my oryginal post, 1. Creating package on prod, 2. Retrieving using mdapi command, 3. unzipping and using sfdx convert. 4. Push to scratch